# Relationship between two Datacontext

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-relationship

I have two database. MasterData and ProductData.
I store the Users and Employees in the MasterData and I store the Tasks in the ProdcutData.
A Task entity has a User property. It shows which user created this Task.

If I used just one Database and one DataContext I could define a one and more relationship between two entities. But I must use two Databases and datacontexts.

Are any solution that I define relationship between two entities that are in different databases, datacontexts?

thanks advance: l.

Comment: DataContext? Are you talking about Linq-to-Sql (`DataContext`) or Entity Framework (`ObjectContext` and `DbContext`)? You must specify your question and tags correctly to get an useful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a full blown answer, but it might get you to think of another solution.

Depending on the DBMS you are using, you might be able to create synonyms or updateable views (or something similar) from one database to the other. That you DataContext can contain the synonyms/views and the tables.

In sql-server:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Well, unless I missed something there is no way to join two entities from different contexts/databases regardless if its L2S or EF. Alternative is pooling all possibly relevant data from two contexts and doing in-memory linq to do relational operations, but that certainly poses performance problems of loading too much data.
Here's a "novel" idea, why not use DataSet? Different table adapters can use different connection strings. It is rather archaic next to L2S/EF but it will offer you most bells & whistles of relationships.

I do have one question, if you keep users and their tasks in separate dbs how do you handle ref integrity?

Answer (score 0):

Synonym is a good solution, but the EF does not support it yet....

http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-ado-net-entity-framework-ef-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1052345-support-for-multiple-databases?ref=title

Thanks again!